# JVM crash occurred in libjvm.so when KlassInfoTable::record_instance(oopDesc*) is called

Tags: java, jvm

My application got crashed with below error. Please help to find what went wrong here.

```
JRE Version : 8.0_65-b17
Linux version : 2.6.18

#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0146d17b, pid=11156, tid=2288950160
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_65-b17) (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (25.65-b01 mixed mode linux-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x4ab17b]  KlassInfoTable::record_instance(oopDesc*)+0xeb
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x09694800):  VMThread [stack: 0x88669000,0x886ea000] [id=11164]

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x00000074

Registers:
EAX=0x00000000, EBX=0x00000000, ECX=0x9e7fea00, EDX=0x8896c110
ESP=0x886e8c90, EBP=0x886e8cb8, ESI=0x0a7ee648, EDI=0x00000000
EIP=0x0146d17b, EFLAGS=0x00010246, CR2=0x00000074

Top of Stack: (sp=0x886e8c90)
0x886e8c90:   8896c110 9e7fea00 00000000 00000000
0x886e8ca0:   00812ff4 00814120 fffffff8 886e8d90
0x886e8cb0:   9e7fea00 09599338 886e8cd8 0146e5bd
0x886e8cc0:   886e8db4 9e7fea00 018fe228 018fe228
0x886e8cd0:   9e7fea00 fffffff8 886e8d08 016d6595
0x886e8ce0:   886e8d90 9e7fea00 fffffff8 fffffff8
0x886e8cf0:   886e8d20 886e8e08 886e8d48 09599258
0x886e8d00:   886e8d90 000003ec 886e8d28 01777e27 

Instructions: (pc=0x0146d17b)
0x0146d15b:   42 04 b2 01 8d 65 f4 88 d0 5b 5e 5f 5d c3 8d b4
0x0146d16b:   26 00 00 00 00 75 56 53 53 8b 02 8b 4d 0c 51 52
0x0146d17b:   ff 50 74 83 c4 10 eb af 90 8d 74 26 00 75 11 56
0x0146d18b:   56 8b 02 8b 4d 0c 51 52 ff 50 74 83 c4 10 eb ba 

Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
EBX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
ECX=0x9e7fea00 is an oop
[C 
 - klass: {type array char}
 - length: 17
EDX=0x8896c110 is pointing into metadata
ESP=0x886e8c90 is an unknown value
EBP=0x886e8cb8 is an unknown value
ESI=0x0a7ee648 is an unknown value
EDI=0x00000000 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x88669000,0x886ea000],  sp=0x886e8c90,  free space=511k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x4ab17b]  KlassInfoTable::record_instance(oopDesc*)+0xeb
V  [libjvm.so+0x4ac5bd]  RecordInstanceClosure::do_object(oopDesc*)+0x2d
V  [libjvm.so+0x714595]  MutableSpace::object_iterate(ObjectClosure*)+0x35
V  [libjvm.so+0x7b5e27]  PSYoungGen::object_iterate(ObjectClosure*)+0x17
V  [libjvm.so+0x771ce6]  ParallelScavengeHeap::object_iterate(ObjectClosure*)+0x16
V  [libjvm.so+0x4ac0f1]  HeapInspection::heap_inspection(outputStream*)+0x1a1
V  [libjvm.so+0x8ce1e1]  VM_GC_HeapInspection::doit()+0x61
V  [libjvm.so+0x8d8197]  VM_Operation::evaluate()+0x47
V  [libjvm.so+0x8d6273]  VMThread::evaluate_operation(VM_Operation*)+0xb3
V  [libjvm.so+0x8d6610]  VMThread::loop()+0x1b0
V  [libjvm.so+0x8d6a75]  VMThread::run()+0x85
V  [libjvm.so+0x7534a9]  java_start(Thread*)+0x119
C  [libpthread.so.0+0x53db]  start_thread+0xcb

VM_Operation (0x02769ef0): GC_HeapInspection, mode: safepoint, requested by thread 0x0aa48000
```

Comment: Did you write this application? If yes: [so] is the place to ask. If no: contact the developer.

Comment: Yes, we have developed our own application in java which uses libjvm.so during execution.

Comment: Well, (SIGSEGV) so you likely have a bug in your native code.

Comment: Looks like JVM bug in heap iterator. Do you use `jmap` or `-XX:+PrintClassHistogram...`?

Comment: There is a similar issue already reported https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6850053 which was closed as cannot reproduce, if you have steps that can be used to reproduce this issye then it can be considered for fix.

Comment: Do we have any solution to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This generally indicates a JVM bug and you should report this via the link referenced in the above.

That in itself won't help you in the short term, given the error is in the pre-built JVM and not in your application code. In these scenarios I have had considerable success by upgrading to a later *minor* JVM version. I see you're using 8.0_65-b17 and there are numerous 8.0 builds superseding this (i.e. not moving up to Java 9, but just a later Java 8 build).

I have also found downgrading on occasions has mitigated such errors.